# Full production ready setup

Tags: installation

I am just starting with Magento and really looking forward to open an actual production store. Would like to know, what is the perfect combination of installs?
(Magento2, ram size?, cpusize? is AWS overkill as the store will be 24/7, disk size needed, is varnish required to be configured if using Magento 2?) a lot of questions, hopefully someone blogged about it. :)